# Mvvmcross Universal Controller Base

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm working on an application that is required for iPad and iPhones, I've been previously using a view controller base for iphones only but now have switched to a Universal Controller.

My base Controller is declared as follows

```
public abstract partial class ControllerBase : MvxViewController
{
}
```

I now in in my other controllers attempt to declare them as

```
public abstract partial class HelloWorld : ControllerBase
{
}
```

The problem occurs as I do not now know to implement which xib file to choose which is normall done in the constructer as follows

```
public HellowWorld ()
: base (UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone ? "HellowWorld_iPhone" : "HellowWorld_iPad", null)
{
}
```

but I don't know how to setup my base controller to accept this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in C# you can just chain your constructors to pass the xib name down to the base constructor. - e.g

```
public ControllerBase ( string xibName, NSBundle bundle)
    : base(xibName, bundle)
{}
```